# Add class to a particular element when second child of list clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to add class on particular element which already have class when second child of list item clicked then remove that class if any other list item clicked.

i can add class onclick of link but don't understand how to add condition when other list item clicked rather then 2nd child so i can remove that added class.

```
<ul class="acf-hl acf-tab-group">
  <li><a href="">tab1</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="">tab2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">tab3</a></li> 
</ul>
<div class="single-item ae0fgf0c hidden-by-tab"></div>
<div class="single-item ae0fgf0b hidden-by-tab"></div>
<h3 class="submit-button">Budget</h3> 
<div class="single-item ae0fgf045"></div>
<div class="single-item ae0fgf0e"></div>
<div class="single-item ae0fgf0cf hidden-by-tab"></div>
<div class="single-item ae0fgf0t hidden-by-tab"></div>
```

Basically its a wordpress custom field plugin so it added ".hidden-by-tab" class when item is clicked to the other items related element and i added a html code h3 before certain class like above

```
<h3 class="submit-button">Budget</h3>
```

Now this h3 will showing up on other tab content part i want to make this hide on other tab content, i just want to show this on 2nd list content.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".acf-field-54f5a4c9a71b0").before('<h3 class="submit-head">BUDGET</h3>');
  $(".acf-field-54f5a4c9a7497").before('<h3 class="submit-head">FUNDING</h3>');      
});
```

Above is the jquery code i use to add h3 before particular classes is there any solution to hide this like the related class hide on other tab, if you see above code add ".active" class above i tried to target the  by that class but not succesfull.

```
if($(.acf-tab-group li:nth-child(2)).hasClass('active')){
  $(.submit-button).addClass("selected");
 }
```

In jsfiddle it add class but in real code it doesn't. please help me out or let me know if there is need of further explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
$('.acf-hl').on('click', 'li', function () {
    if ($(this).index() == 1 && $(this).hasClass('active')) $('h3.submit-button').addClass('active');
    else $('.active').removeClass('active');
    return false;
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/amrq3bf4/4/

Another Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/amrq3bf4/5/

Comment: Tushar thanks for reply actually active class added by plugin code, i want to add class on <h3> when click on 2nd list for others it will be removed.  i supposed you understand now.

Comment: Looks we are almost there @Tushar but active class not removed when click on other tab please check.

Comment: Buddy isn't there is a way we can remove class when click on other list item except 2nd list item.

Comment: if nth-child(2) have active class then add class to h3 otherwise remove that, is that clear bro.  i am trying to create fiddle also

Comment: I got you buddy solution work you are true jquery wizard bro thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
 $('.acf-tab-group > li').click(function(){
 var flag=$(this).hasClass('active');

if(flag){$('.submit-button').addClass("selected")}
else{$('.submit-button').removeAttr('class').addClass('submit-button')}


})
```

removeAttr will remove entire class attribute so i have added `.submit-button` class again.